# Integrating adMobs in sprite kit scene

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to integrate **"admobs"** into an scene. I'm trying to do that by doing it `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in the `viewController`. I'm trying it out in a blank scene with **0** nodes, so there is nothing that can cause problems in the scene.

The problem is that the ad is not showing in my scene. I'm getting following log message:

```
To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
```

but i am creating the request in `createRequest` method.

This is my code:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;


    if (!skView.scene) {

        self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape];
        self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-AdId";
        self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
        self.bannerView.delegate = self;
        self.bannerView.center = CGPointMake(skView.bounds.size.width / 2, skView.bounds.size.height - (bannerView_.frame.size.height / 2));
        [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
        [self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * scene = [Menu sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];


    }

}

-(GADRequest *)createRequest {
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
    return request;
}

-(void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"Ad Reveived");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Mention that as well.

Comment: But where are you calling this "createRequest" function?

Comment: In the ViewController.m file

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the following code;

```
[self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

 with:

GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
r.testing = YES;
[self.bannerView loadRequest:r];
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Seems to work great, but how can i remove the banner in a specific scene+